# Power of nth number (table) in C

Tags: c, function

I'm making program that prints their nth power for numbers from 1 to 20, using recursive and non-recursive function. I would like to give an option for user to enter real numbers. How to do that? Can it be done without pow function? Thank you for your help!

Comment: keiski, "option for user to enter real numbers" --> Is that only for `num`, `exponent` or both?

Comment: Hi chux! I want to give a user a choice to enter real number for exponent and num.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to raise a number to a real exponent `x`

```
a^x
```

you can compute it as

```
e^(x ln a)
```

so you can write a function like

```
double mypow( double base, double exponent )
{
  return exp( exponent * log( base ) ) 
}
```

If you want to get deep into the weeds and create your own implementations of `exp` and `log`, you can use the Taylor series

```
e^x = 1 + x + ((x^2)/2!) + ((x^3)/3!) ...
```

and

```
ln x = 2( u + (u^3)/3 + (u^5)/5 ... ), u = (x+1)/(x-1)
```

Personally, I would just use the `pow` function.

Answer (score 0):

In making `double keiski_pow(double num, double exponent)` consider different code for certain conditions.

```
// exponent == 0, num != 0
return 1

// exponent == 0, num == 0
Domain error

// num > 0
return exp(log(num)*exponent)
// or more accurately
return exp2(log2(num)*exponent)

// num == 0, exponent < 0
Infinity

// num < 0, exponent is an integer > 0.  
// Integer test for `double`: trunc(exponent) == exponent
t = keiski_pow(num, exponent/2)
return t*t*(exponent%2 ? num : 1)
// or 
t = keiski_pow(fabs(num), exponent)
return t*exponent%2 ? -1 : 1)

// num < 0, exponent is an integer < 0
return 1.0/keiski_pow(num, -exponent)

// num < 0, exponent is not an integer
Domain error
```

I think this covers most cases.  (NaN are another story)

---

Note: `recursion()` is *very very slow* for large `exponent`.  Try `recursion(1.0, 1e15)`.

A much faster recursive solution:

```
double recursion_alt(double num, double exponent) {
  // Code only valid when exponent has a whole number value
  assert(exponent = trunc(exponent)); 

  if (exponent > 0.0) {
    double exponent_mod2 = fmod(exponent, 2.0);
    double exponent_div2 = (exponent - exponent_mod2)/2.0;
    double t = recursion_alt(num, exponent_div2);
    return t*t*(exponent_mod2 ? num : 1.0);
  }

  if (exponent < 0.0) {
    return 1.0/recursion_alt(num, -exponent);
  }

  return 1.0;
}
```